# recaptcha, проверка формы

Tags: ajax, recaptcha

Доброго времени суток, есть рабочая рекапча в скрипте которого только одно поле в БД добавляется, больше одного никак не получается, просто POST параметры не передаются

```
//отправка формы и проверка капчи
$("#send").click(function(e){

e.preventDefault();
var  login = $("#login").val();
var  email = $("#email").val();
    $.ajax({

        url: 'handler.php',
        type: "post",
    data:"login=" + login +"&g-recaptcha-response=" + grecaptcha.getResponse(),


        success: function(data){
            if(data==='ok'){

        $("span#err").text("ok").css("color","lime");

            }if(data==='recaptch error'){
    $("span#err").text("неправильно введена капча").css("color","yellow");

            }
            if(data==='pls enter captcha'){
    $("span#err").text("ввведите капчу").css("color","orange");

            }
        }
    });

});
```

////////////////

```
handler.php
if($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']){
    $captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    $secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";


     $res = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=" . $secret . "&response=".$captcha),true);

     if($res['success']){
         echo "ok";
              $login = $_POST['login'];
              $email = $_POST['email'];
         global $connection;
    $insert = mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO news (login,email) 
    VALUES
    ('$login','$email')");

     }else{

         echo "recaptch error";
     }


     }else{
         echo 'pls enter captcha';

     }
```

`data:"login=" + login +"&g-recaptcha-response=" + grecaptcha.getResponse(),` в этой строке никак не получается отправить данные больше чем одного поля, как решить эту задачу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передавать параметры массивом. [JQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
data: { login: login, g-recaptcha-response: grecaptcha.getResponse() }
```

В PHP ловить `$_POST['login']` и `$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']`

Comment: "g-recaptcha-response" это параметр и должен состоять в кавычках и тогда заработает, спасибо за помощь)